# have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I want to use a third-party Android project in my project, so I exported the source of this third party project to a jar file and then imported the jar file to my project's Android Dependencies. I added  this code in my class:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
            "com.mobilevisualsearch",
            "com.mobilevisualsearch.ActivityImageDetail");

    String strImageSourcePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Camera/P40101-165253.jpg";
    Bundle bd = new Bundle();
    bd.putString("strPhotoFileFullName", strImageSourcePath);

    Intent it = new Intent();
    it.putExtras(bd);
    it.setComponent(componentName);
    startActivity(it);
```

`com.mobilevisualsearch.ActivityImageDetail` is a class of the third-party project. My `AndroidManifest.xml` was added as

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobilevisualsearch.ActivityImageDetail"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

This`<activity>` is under `<application>`. When I run my app I get an error.
This is the Logcat log:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mobilevisualsearch/com.mobilevisualsearch.ActivityImageDetail}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Must check it is imported properly with Green Mark?

Comment: try this -> Intent it = new Intent(this,com.mobilevisualsearch.ActivityImageDetail.class) instead of setting in component

Comment: @user try changing `ComponentName` constructor call to : `ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
            "com.mobilevisualsearch",
            "ActivityImageDetail");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix this problem?

Step #1: Get rid of your `ComponentName` and the `setComponent()` call

Step #2: Replace your `Intent` initialization with `Intent it = new Intent(this, ActivityImageDetail.class);`, adding the `import` for `ActivityImageDetail` if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
com.mobilevisualsearch.ActivityImageDetail
```

as it console  notice you that class not found exception , Check that third party project is add to your project or not

try to import the ActivityImageDetail in your class and check is it exist or not

or if you are trying to open the third party application which is installed in your device, then no need to install in the manifest, check the app is exist or not in your device